# how to make viewport display diffuse maps in full color? (2.8)

Tags: 3d-view, image

I am  painting textures onto 3d meshes so I need to see the color exactly as it is, but in texture paint mode my colors are 100% bright (white is 100%), but in viewport colors get as if it was in lower light (white is like 80%ish grey).

How to make viewport display diffuse maps in full color (like displayed in textures) ?

flat shading is on, still no result.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to experiment the solution out. Here's how:

Rendering tab (evee rendering selected) -> color management -> display device (set to REC709)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting viewport Overlays -> Texture paint Opacity to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but with Vertex Color insted. I realized if I set Viewport Shading to "Texture" instead of "Vertex" it displayed full brightness. If anyone needs this info.